# Windows Server 2008 r2 Server VPS: every connection capped at 500kb/s

Tags: windows, connection, performance

I have a strange problem on a Windows Server 2008 r2 Server based VPS. My provider gives me unmetered and unlimited bandwidth, and obviously full root access (I administer the machine via RDP without using any web interface to have complete control). I noticed something very odd, because I see that every single connection (http, ftp, mail etc.) seems 'limited' to 500kb/s. So if I try to download a file via http I go to 500kb/s, if I download a second one that one gets another 500kb/s, and so on till I fill the maximum connection of my cable connection from home (50mbit/s). So from the server I can get a total of almost 5mb/s but every single connection arrives top to 500kb/s.

I tried the same test via ftp on the same server, and in upload and download I get the same results..one download or upload max 500kb/s, if I start another one that one as well is up to 500kb/s and so on. The same thing happens if I try to send a big file or download something big via email (imap and smtp).

I checked all the single server services and I can't find any limit in their configurations, and as far as I know Windows Firewall cannot limit the bandwidth this way..

Any suggestion about how to test more this problem or how to solve it? I find it very odd and the provider as well.

Comment: Have you called them to ask?

Comment: Yes and they confirmed there's no limit or metering, and that I should investigate more in the OS settings..

Answer (score 1):

I see this rather often when moving customers from one Managed Service Provider to another.  Usually this is a configuration somewhere on their network to ensure that one session doesn't take all the bandwidth within the facility.  You probably won't be able to change this as it's probably within the Quality of Service settings within their routers.

Comment: Yes this is what I thought and I asked them, but they say they never had this problem before..and I talked with a Sysadmin not the customer service. I think it depends on QoS on some router, but I don't know how to ask/demonstrate them, because if that's the case is against the contract I signed.

Comment: It might also be their upstream provider that is causing the problem.  You'll have to do a screen sharing session with the sysadmin and have him watch you download one thing and see if cap at 500k, then start a second download and have them both cap at 500k each, etc.